# odbcCommand with oracle procedure does not update records

Tags: c#, oracle, stored-procedures, odbc

I am calling Oracle Stored Procedure in C# using odbc, i have written the following code

```
    OdbcCommand cmd = new OdbcCommand("{CALL sp_UpdateFileStatus(?)}", con);              
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Param", OdbcType.Int).Value = 74;
    int rows = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

cmd.ExecuteNonQuery() always returns 1  it does not update the records in table, when i run procedure in Oracle SQL Developer it works perfectly. i don't understand what is wrong here.
i have checked connection string it is perfect. Can any one help what can be wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have probably forgotten to `COMMIT` your changes.

Comment: Great it works. I have used OdbcTransaction and at the end transaction.commit(); Thank you very very much Michal Niklas you are awesome. Thanks again.